# Reference file (.js) is not getting displayed on php /HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I have very strange problem, even though I am very new to this approach please suggest me if I can do something in other way.

Problem:

I have following script

```
<script type="text/javascript"  id="myscript" src="http://piclaunch.com/i/i2/embed.js" sid="10"></script>
```

Which is working very well and showing me "Contact us " button on the page.if I just include the above script to my page: http://piclaunch.com/i/f.php

but on this word press site: http://whatsq.com/ , same script does not list the "Contact Us" option even though the embed.js of my script is loading fine . (I am getting alert from my script on page load)
Just for ref:

```
http://whatsq.com/f.php
```

at this page it works well again.

Any pointers to solve this, would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Pic

Comment: Where did you include the javascript file for the wordpress site

Comment: there was no change in wordpress site except addition of script using some plugin. I think its too many versions of jqery and other whcih are conflicting with each other. you may see : http://whatsq.com/f.php at this page it works fine too

Comment: Where did you add the script

Comment: I am sorry Aaron, not getting your question. I have all the script at piclaunch.com . and only
<script type="text/javascript"  id="myscript" src="http://piclaunch.com/i/i2/embed.js" sid="10"></script>
was added to wordpress site suing html snippet plugin.

Comment: no script in your wordpress

Comment: In what file did you physically add this line `<script type="text/javascript" id="myscript" src="piclaunch.com/i/i2/embed.js"; sid="10"></script>`

Comment: I added it to the theme's header.php file now. and it's no more giving me alert which can be see on  http://whatsq.com/f.php

Comment: @PiclaunchS Don't include it in the header. Try including it in `footer.php` before `<body>` tag ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one..I noticed I was not using

```
http:// in the src
```

for the file name and there was an element which js file was not able to find and was not processing further. After debugging I was able to remove that object . at least I can see the buttons now ..but its not as clear as I see on demo site..

Answer (score 0):

Launch developer tools and verify whether the embed.js script line is added to the web page or not.

I see the above script line in http://piclaunch.com/i/f.php but not in http://whatsq.com/

Comment: I am able to see alert message from embed.js file , so I think its loading it.